# Sobrecarga de operadores C++, a variável auxiliar é necessária nesse caso?

Tags: c, c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes, sobrecarga

Estou estudando pelo livro Introdução à Programação Orientada a Objetos com C++ (Antonio Mendes da Silva Filho), e implementei um exemplo dele da seguinte forma:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Contador{

    public:
        Contador(int c = 0){contador = c;};
        int getContador(){return contador;};
        Contador operator++(){
            ++contador;
            return contador; };
    private:
        unsigned int contador;
};

int main(){

    Contador c1, c2, c3;

    ++c1;
    ++c2;
    ++c2;
    ++c2;
    c3 = ++c2;

    cout << "c1: " << c1.getContador() << endl;
    cout << "c2: " << c2.getContador() << endl; 
    cout << "c3: " << c3.getContador() << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

O retorno do contador é apenas para que possa ser feita a atribuição em `c3 = ++c2;`

O programa rodou como esperado, imprimindo

```
c1 = 1
c2 = 4
c3 = 4
```

Porém na resposta do livro ele acrescenta uma variável auxiliar no seguinte trecho:

```
Contador operator++(){
            ++contador;
            Contador temp;
            temp.contador = contador;
            return temp; };
```

Compilando, o resultado é exatamente o mesmo. Esta variável auxiliar é desnecessária, certo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro o código não funciona adequadamente não. [Veja que dependendo de como o operador for usado dá problema](http://ideone.com/aSZBV0). O exemplo do livro está um pouco melhor porque pelo menos retorna um objeto do tipo `Contador` e não a variável `contador`, que são coisas bem distintas. [Mas ele não funciona também](http://ideone.com/3tEWVp). Assim funciona:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Contador {
    unsigned int contador;
public:
    Contador(int c = 0) { contador = c; };
    int getContador() { return contador; };
    Contador& operator++() {
        ++contador;
        return *this;
    };
};

int main() {
    Contador c1, c2, c3;
    ++c1;
    ++c2;
    ++c2;
    ++c2;
    c3 = ++c2;
    ++(++(++c1));
    cout << "c1: " << c1.getContador() << endl;
    cout << "c2: " << c2.getContador() << endl; 
    cout << "c3: " << c3.getContador() << endl; 
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Mrr7zw). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cmssfbwq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Operator/Overload.cpp).

Assim está ok para o operador de pré incremento porque agora você tem uma referência para o objeto sendo retornada e não usando um objeto temporário que o compilador cria.

Vai fazer o pós incremento também? Aí precisa de um objeto temporário para retornar como resultado da operação e fazer a operação no objeto. Assim:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Contador{
    unsigned int contador;
public:
    Contador(int c = 0) { contador = c; };
    int getContador() { return contador; };
    Contador& operator++() {
        ++contador;
        return *this;
    };
    Contador operator++(int) {
        Contador temp(*this);
        ++*this;
        return temp;
    };
};

int main() {
    Contador c1, c2, c3;
    ++c1;
    ++c2;
    ++c2;
    ++c2;
    c3 = ++c2;
    ++(++(++c1));
    c1++;
    c2++;
    c3++;
    cout << "c1: " << c1.getContador() << endl;
    cout << "c2: " << c2.getContador() << endl; 
    cout << "c3: " << c3.getContador() << endl; 
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/yJUyS5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cmssfbwq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Operator/Overload2.cpp).

Se não fez alguma confusão com os dois operadores, talvez o livro não seja tão bom, mas não posso afirmar sem conhecê-lo e saber do contexto em que está usado.

Comment: Continuei lendo e mais à frente ele trocou essa parte por `Contador operator++(){ 
    ++contador;
    return Contador(contador);
}`

Comment: Que provavelmente é um erro também.

Comment: esse `Contador(contador)` está chamando o construtor?

Comment: Exatamente, cria uma nova instância, mas no mínimo não é eficiente.

Comment: Sobre o pós incremento, eu implementei simplesmente assim: `Contador operator++(int){
   return contador;
   contador++;
  }`

Comment: O seu não incrementa nada, porque o incremento ocorre depois do `return`, nunca chega nessa linha. O dele está incrementando antes. Não está fazendo confusão não?

Comment: Opa, fiz sim, na verdade o dele é `return Contador(contador++);`, copiei errado.

Answer (score 1):

Suponho que ele tenha colocado a variável temp para deixar de uma forma mais didática, pois ele estaria retornando 2 vezes o contador e assim poderia gerar dúvidas.